# Dimensions of a convolution?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, onnx

I have some questions regarding how this convolution is calculated and its output dimension. I'm familiar with simple convolutions with a nxm kernel, using strides, dilations or padding, thats not a problem, but this dimensions seems odd to me. Since the model that I'm using is pretty well known [onnx-mnist](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/master/vision/classification/mnist), I assume it is correct.

So, my point is:

- If the input has a dimensions of 1x1x28x28, how is the output 1x8x28x28?
- W denotes the kernel. How can it be 8x1x5x5? As far as I know, the first dimension is the batch size, but here I'm just doing inference with 1 input. Does this make sense?
- I'm implementing from scratch this convolution operator, and so far it works for 1x1x28x28 and a kernel of 1x1x5x5, but that extra dimensions doesn't make sense to me.

Find attached the convolution that I'm trying to do, hope is not too `onnx` specific.

[image: model]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see the code you are using but I guess 8 is the **number of kernels**. This means you apply 8 different kernels on your input with the size 5x5 over a batch size of 1. That is how you get 1x8x28x28 in the output, the 8 denotes the number of activation maps (one for each kernel).

The numbers of your kernel dimensions (8x1x5x5) explained:

- **8:** Number of different filters/kernels (will be number of output maps per image)
- **1:** Number of input channels. If your input image was RGB instead of grayscale, this would be 3 instead of 1.
- **5:** First spatial dimension
- **5:** Second spatial dimension

Comment: If there are 8 different kernels with 5x5 elements each one, why isn't the kernel size `1x8x5x5` instead of `8x1x5x5`? Or maybe that second dimension would be different than 1 if a 3D kernel was used?

Comment: Your second assumption is correct. You have a 3D kernel but your input has only one channel, therefore it is `8x1x5x5` (Number of kernels x number of input channels x first spatial x second spatial). The same filters are used for each image in a batch therefore you do not have something like `1x8x1x5x5`